# How to transform coordinates for a geometry in Javascript Topology Suite JSTS

Tags: javascript, jsts

I would like to transform coordinates of geometries in JSTS (Javascript Topology Suite).

I want to use a coordinate filter so I don't need to worry about what type of geometry is being transformed (e.g. polygon, multipolygon).

Docs here suggest I could use a CoordinateFilter https://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/jsts.geom.CoordinateFilter.html

e.g. My filter function could look something like:

```
var filter = function(coord){
    coord.x += 100
    coord.y += 200
}
```

But these docs seem totally different to the compiled JSTS version on the demo page, version "1.6.1 (9be7f16)" https://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/

Since I expect to use version 1.6.1 from the demo page, any ideas how to perform the coordinate transform?

I understand that I could parse through all the various coordinates, linear rings, holes etc for each type of geometry but I am hoping I can create a generic coordinate transform function and apply it to any geometry.

Any ideas where I should be looking to achieve this?

-- Edit --

I managed to get this working with a hack... I'd still like to know how to do it properly by using the correct interfaces... My filter function now looks like this:

```
var transformCoordinatesFilter = {
  interfaces_: function() {
    // Hack to work around interface checks in jsts
    // This effectively ensures that any check for 
    // this.interfaces_().indexOf(<some interface>) > -1
    /returns true
    // If only I could set the correct interfaces so this was not necessary
    return {
      indexOf: function() {
        return true
      },
    }
  },
  filter: function(coord) {
    coord.x += 100
    coord.y += 200
  },
}

featureToTransform.apply(transformCoordinatesFilter)
```